# ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added error

Tags: c#

This is a strange one, i have moved some code that was originally tested in some standalone software to the main software.

**Code:**

```
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    foreach (HtmlElement inputTag in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        var tagIdentifier = Helpers.ExtractIdentifierForAutoFill(inputTag.OuterHtml, username + "|" + password + "|" + email + "|" + url);
                        Helpers.ReturnMessage(tagIdentifier.ToString());
                        Helpers.InputFieldsDebugLogging(inputTag.OuterHtml);
                        Helpers.ReturnMessage(tagIdentifier.Item1 + " -> " + tagIdentifier.Item2 + " -> " + tagIdentifier.Item3);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagIdentifier.Item3))
                        {
                            if (tagIdentifier.Item1 == "id")
                            {
                                webBrowser.Document.GetElementById(tagIdentifier.Item2).SetAttribute("value", tagIdentifier.Item3);
                            }

                            if (tagIdentifier.Item1 == "name")
                            {
                                foreach (HtmlElement id in webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName(tagIdentifier.Item2))
                                {
                                    id.SetAttribute("value", tagIdentifier.Item3);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var ignore = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\form-ai-ignore.txt");
                            if (!ignore.Any(tagIdentifier.Item2.Contains) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagIdentifier.Item2))
                            {
                                var fi = new FormTeachAIFields(this, tagIdentifier.Item2)
                                {
                                    // ...
                                };
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }));
```

The error when debugging is:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
```

When i check what line the error is coming from it says it is on the invoke line: `Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>`

When debugging more it seems the code is going no further than this part:

```
var tagIdentifier = Helpers.ExtractIdentifierForAutoFill(inputTag.OuterHtml, username + "|" + password + "|" + email + "|" + url);
```

I have included below the methods used:

```
        public static Tuple<string, string, string> ExtractIdentifierForAutoFill(string input_field, string account)
        {
            var identifier = "";
            var id_or_name = "";
            try
            {
                if (input_field.Contains("id="))
                {
                    Match token_m = Regex.Match(input_field, @"id=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    if (token_m.Success)
                    {
                        identifier = token_m.Groups[1].Value;
                        id_or_name = "id";
                    }
                }

                if (input_field.Contains("name="))
                {
                    Match token_m = Regex.Match(input_field, @"name=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    if (token_m.Success)
                    {
                        identifier = token_m.Groups[1].Value;
                        id_or_name = "name";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }
            var tuple = new Tuple<string, string, string>(id_or_name, identifier, GetAccountDetails(account, PredictValue(identifier), identifier));
            return tuple;
        }

        public static string GetAccountDetails(string accountDetailsString, string inputValue, string field)
        {
            string[] macro = accountDetailsString.Split('|');
            var returnValue = "";
            //ReturnMessage(inputValue);
            switch (inputValue)
            {
                case "USERNAME":
                    returnValue = macro[0];
                    break;
                case "PASSWORD":
                    returnValue = macro[1];
                    break;
                case "EMAIL":
                    returnValue = macro[2];
                    break;
                case "URL":
                    returnValue = macro[3];
                    break;
                case Helpers.CustomMacroField:
                    //TODO: duplicated code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field))
                    {
                        var values = ReadAiFields(@"LogicFiles\form-ai-fields-custom.txt");
                        var foundKey = values.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => field.Contains(key));
                        if (foundKey != null) returnValue = values[foundKey];
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    returnValue = "";
                    break;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static string PredictValue(string inputValue)
        {
            string returnValue = "";
            inputValue = inputValue.ToLower();
            var values = ReadAiFields(@"LogicFiles\form-ai-fields.txt");

            var foundKey = values.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => inputValue.Contains(key));
            if (foundKey != null)
            {
                returnValue = values[foundKey];
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> ReadAiFields(string path)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (!File.Exists(path)) return values;
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                string line = lines[i];
                if (line.StartsWith("#"))
                {
                    string[] keys = line.Remove(0, 1).Split('|');
                    string value = lines[i + 1];
                    foreach (string key in keys)
                    {
                        values.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

I never wrote the above code it was modified recently, which did work in the standalone app but not after i moved the exact code over with copy / paste, from reading up on the error i *think* it is to do with the dictionary, would that be right? i'm not exactly sure of the issue, is there anything standing out in the code i might have missed? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying you are trying to add an item to the dictionary with a key that has already been used to add an item to that dictionary.

Comment: It's probably the file read by `ReadAiFields` that contains duplicate entries

Comment: That's strange, when i execute the software, i'm not actually adding an entries, it should just be reading hmm that's strange in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is telling us that we're attempting to add a key to a dictionary that already contains that key, which is not allowed. The only code that you've shared that does this is:

```
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    values.Add(key, value);
}
```

To avoid the problem, we simply check first if the key already exists. If it does, we have a decision to make:

1. Leave the existing value
2. Assign a new value

To leave existing values, we can just ignore keys that already exist:

```
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    if(!values.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        values.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

To assign the new value, we don't need to check if the key exists, we just add it in a different manner:

```
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    // This will add a new key/value pair, unless the key already
    // exists, in which case it will assign a new value to the key
    values[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: This appears to have been the issue! thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem is here.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ReadAiFields(string path)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (!File.Exists(path)) return values;
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                string line = lines[i];
                if (line.StartsWith("#"))
                {
                    string[] keys = line.Remove(0, 1).Split('|');
                    string value = lines[i + 1];
                    foreach (string key in keys)
                    {
                        values.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

Not knowing the underlying data structure, I would assume that each line contains data for a different object of the same type. This being said, it would work fine if you only had one line, but as soon as you try to move to the next line it would throw that error. Basically, I am assuming your data looks like below.

```
#username|password|email|url
user1|1234pass|john@example.com|somethingcool.com
#username|password|email|url
user2|123456pass|jane@example.com|somethingcooler.com
```

If this is the case then you actually are dealing with a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and you would get the value for `John` just fine but would error out on `Jane` because you are trying to add `Jane` to the same dictionary that `John` is in. Am I close to your situation? If so, you could fix this by using the following.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> ReadAiFields(string path)
    {
        var values = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return values;
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];
            if (line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string[] keys = line.Remove(0, 1).Split('|');
                string value = lines[i + 1];
                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    dictionary.Add(key, value);
                }
                values.Add(dictionary);
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
```

This would, of course, break your call to this method. If you know it is always the first one (or at least know it is always in a certain position) you could use the following.

```
var foundKey = values[0].Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => inputValue.Contains(key));
```

Comment: Patrick, you are right in the example :) the thing is, i only use 1 set of credentials on an execution, only ```john's``` credentials would be used (as these are taken from an .xml file further up the code) it does appear that ```Dictionary``` method is the issue here.